# Template internal classes based on parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I have a question related to a template class implementation design.

A template AT can be specialized with template parameters A1 and A2 only:

```
AT<A1> a;

or

AT<A2> a;
```

The template has a function that may use B1 and B2 classes. Specifically, when the template is specialized with A1 class, the function should use B1 and for A2, B2 should be used.
For example:

```
template< class T > class AT : public A
{
  int size;

  public:
    int f()
    {
        if ( dynamic_cast<A1*> this != 0 ) {
            size = sizeof( B1 );
        }
        else {
            size = sizeof( B2 );
        }
    }

    ...
};
```

As B1 and B2 are classes related to internal A1 and A2 implementation, it is preferably to not make end user aware about their existence, so specialization of the template like

```
AT<A1, B1> a;
```

is not acceptable.

What is the best way to design such template class and permit internal differentiation based on the class that the template was specialized with?

Thank you!

Comment: I have changed the tag `rtti` to `template`. The question is more related to *compile time* templates than to *RunTime Type Information*.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. What is `a AT<AI>;` supposed to mean? (It is not valid syntax afaict.) `AT<A1,B1>` isn't possible at all, AT only has one template argument. `dynamic_cast` is a runtime thing, I don't think you want that there - is that part of your problem?

Comment: While rereading the question I am starting to doubt whether what I understood and what you need are the same. Do you intend on using the `AT<T>` polymorphically through pointers/references to `A`? If so, then you do need RTTI, but that should most probably be solved by means of making `f` a `virtual` function and having the implementation dispatch to the appropriate override.

Comment: To David and Mat: usage of A1 involves usage of B1, A2 -> B2. The intention is to hide knowledge of B1/B2 from the users of the template. Yes, I am going to use the instances polymorphically, but I don't think it makes a difference for the implementation.

Comment: Thank you David and stativ! The type traits do the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a simple type trait to map the types it:

```
template <typename T>
struct B_type;           // Generic type mapping declaration (undefined)
template <>
struct B_type<A1> {      // Mapping of A1 -> B1
   typedef B1 type;
};
template <>
struct B_type<A2> {      // Mappint of A2 -> B2
   typedef B2 type;
};
```

And then use it internally:

```
template <typename T>
int AT<T>::f() {
   return sizeof( typename B_type<T>::type );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a simpler cases you can use type traits.

If you need something more sophisticated you can use private/protected inheritance or just create the specialized object (Thanks to David pointing out the fact it's not possible to use a member class) which has an explicit specialization for A1 and A2 and which selects the right function.

```
template<> class sizeofFunc<A1>
{
    public:
        static int getSize(T obj) {
            return sizeof(B1);
        }
};

template<> class sizeofFunc<A2>
{
  public:
      static int getSize(T obj) {
          return sizeof(B2);
      }
};

template< class T > class AT : public A, private sizeofFunc<T>
{
  int size;

  public:
    int f()
    {
        size = getSize(something);
    }

    ...
};
```

Comment: You would need to refactor the code. The language does not allow you to specialize a template member inside the class definition (i.e. the `sizeofFunc<X>` have to be moved outside of `AT`). Additionally, you do not need to provide a definition of the unspecialized template `sizeofFunc`.

Comment: In fact I'm used to use private inheritance in this case. This must be reason why I learned to use inheritance in such cases. I hope I'll remember it better this time. Thank you for pointing it out.